# Find delimiter in strtok()

Tags: c, delimiter, strtok

I am new to C programming.
I am trying to split a string using strtok(), using multiple delimiters. The line of code is :

```
char *token = strtok(st, " +-*/^()");
```

I want to know at which delimiter it got split. Is it possible? Please help.
I mean in this example whether the token got split at space, plus, minus, etc.

Comment: Not possible with `strtok()`. You'll have to write your own version that provides a way to capture the matched character or use a different approach.

Comment: Oh ok thank you @Shawn. But is there any other inbuilt function that does that for me ?

Comment: Not with `strtok` because it overwrites the first character match with a string terminator.

Comment: Oh ok thanks @WeatherVane. But is there any other in-built function that does this for me? Or do I have to make my own function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strtok` changes the found delimiter by the zero character `'\0'`. So it is impossible to determine what delimiter was encountered.

Instead of the function `strtok` you can use functions `strspn` and `strcspn`. Using these functions you can determine what delimiter was encountered.

For example

```
size_t n = strcspn( st, " +-*/^()" );

if ( st[n] != '\0' )
{
    switch ( st[n] )
    {
    case ' ':
       //...
       break;
    case '+':
       //...
       break;
    //...
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't mind for disturbing you, but doesn't it give only the first appearance of the character and string respectively but what if I want to use strtok in a loop repeatedly. Please help. Plus what is size_t used for?

Comment: @SuryaMajumder Who does prevent you to use strspn and strcspn also in a loop?!

Comment: @SuryaMajumder size_t is an unsigned integer type that is used to store string lengths.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vlad from Moscow. Thank you very much.